# How to refresh data on jsp page for every request

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, session, servlets

Here in my application i am using Hibernate,JSP,Servlet.Situation is i am taking some data from DB and setting it as session attribute and accessing same session attribute at JSP and displaying it. Here data on jsp page is getting updated only after the logout and login in application instead of this i want to update the data at every new request to my jsp page.So how we can get the data in session for every new request to jsp page?

Comment: You can use a `Filter`.

Comment: It looks like you may want to store them in the `requestScope` and not in the `sessionScope`.

Comment: Well, it would be cool to see some code, but it seems like you could do what you need with a filter in your web.xml file...

Comment: @fvu but will it work for send redirect request?

Comment: @Rohan hard to say without seeing any code.  But you could also have the redirector update the data in the session or am I missing something here?

Comment: @Rohan to clarify a bit what I meant: if you use `response.sendRedirect` you'll leave the request chain, and storing data in the request scope obviously won't work then.  If you use RequestDispatcher.forward(request, response) you'll remain in the same request chain and you'll be able to use requestScope.